# Gatsby Build stuck on Building Static HTML for Pages

Tags: reactjs, build, terminal, gatsby, production

Im trying to build my Gatsby project into production files. When running the command Gatsby build, the process runs and gets stuck at "Building static html for pages"

Terminal:

```
$ gatsby build
success open and validate gatsby-configs — 0.006 s
success load plugins — 0.419 s
success onPreInit — 0.064 s
success delete html and css files from previous builds — 0.257 s
success initialize cache — 0.006 s
success copy gatsby files — 0.061 s
success onPreBootstrap — 0.010 s
success source and transform nodes — 0.155 s
success building schema — 0.173 s
success createPages — 0.000 s
success createPagesStatefully — 0.047 s
success onPreExtractQueries — 0.004 s
success update schema — 0.022 s
warning Using the global `graphql` tag is deprecated, and will not be supported in v3.
Import it instead like:  import { graphql } from 'gatsby' in file:
/website/src/components/image.js
success extract queries from components — 0.266 s
success run static queries — 0.229 s — 6/6 26.29 queries/second
success run page queries — 0.003 s — 2/2 902.62 queries/second
success write out page data — 0.004 s
success write out redirect data — 0.001 s
success onPostBootstrap — 0.000 s

info bootstrap finished - 4.846 s

success Building production JavaScript and CSS bundles — 8.720 s
⡀ Building static HTML for pages{ department: 'obj1',
  numEmployees: 2,
  avgHrs: 18,
  avgRate: 15,
  other: 200 }
{ department: 'obj2',
  numEmployees: 4,
  avgHrs: 17,
  avgRate: 13,
  other: 150 }
{ department: 'obj3',
  numEmployees: 3,
  avgHrs: 20,
  avgRate: 22,
  other: 250 }
[ 'department', 'numEmployees', 'avgHrs', 'avgRate', 'other' ]
0
0
[ 'department', 'numEmployees', 'avgHrs', 'avgRate', 'other' ]
1
1
[ 'department', 'numEmployees', 'avgHrs', 'avgRate', 'other' ]
2
2
undefined
undefined
⢀ Building static HTML for pages /website/public/render-page.js:27034
    var el = document.getElementById("myChart" + index);
             ^

ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at charting (/website/public/render-page.js:27034:14)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/website/public/render-page.js:27103:9)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:290:5)
⠁ Building static HTML for pages
```

It keeps running, without throwing an error and stopping. I created a Gatsby starter and ran the same command, where it finished building in around 30 seconds. What is preventing my website from building?

Comment: Is "myChart" a component or is it in the pages folder ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that on the "server-side", as in, when Gatsby is rendering the pages statically, they are run within an environment that doesn't have a concept of a "window" or a "document", so while your code here might work when it's run inside a browser, it fails here.

A simple trick is to wrap anything that requires there to be a document in an if statement

`if(typeof(document) !== 'undefined') { ... }` (or your preferred alternative).

There are also components that you can use to wrap chunks of the page, for instance [React NoSSR](https://github.com/kadirahq/react-no-ssr), which does this like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import NoSSR from 'react-no-ssr';
import MyChart from './MyChart.jsx';

const MyChartPage = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>My Chart Page</h2>
    <hr />
    <NoSSR>
      <MyChart />
    </NoSSR>
  </div>
);
```

When this is rendered server-side, the NoSSR rule ignores rendering, and your code requiring a `document` runs only on the client-side.

Comment: I think the question is when there's an error, why gatsby doesn't stop building but instead hanging.